# Python: matipulations with Chrome browser

Tags: python, webbrowser-control

I want to write a code, which is copying source code of website after each reload. Can anyone say a library by which i can realize my desires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that simply with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

First `pip install requests`.

Then:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://your_url)
print(r.text)
```

If you want to manipulate html you should use [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), or [selenium](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjygtC6k4TWAhXGs1QKHc-wAkUQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fselenium-python.readthedocs.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNEKW5YbePdtoyreYl86QsDyZhhZAA).

Comment: And i dont need any specific library?

Comment: requests, beautifull soup and selenium python are libraries. You just need to install them with pip.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this library: urllib2

```
import urllib2

p= urllib2.urlopen('http://write_your_address')    
content = p.read()
```

I hope this help you ;)